# Aprimorar qualidade da imagem - Upload Facebook API

Tags: facebook

Estou realizando a criação de um post no Facebook com uma foto com o codigo a seguir:

```
FB.api(
        '/me/photos',
        'POST',
        {"url": imagem,"message": texto_publicaco},
        function(response) {
            alert("Postagem criada");
        }
);
```

A variável `imagem` contem a URL para onde eu realizei o upload no servidor do site que estou trabalhando. A imagem está em JPG e no servidor carrega normalmente.

Mas quando faço o post no facebook a qualidade da imagem baixa MUITO mesmo.

Existe alguma maneira de melhorar nem que seja um pouco a qualidade da imagem que é carregada la?

Answer (score 0):

A resposta que encontrei foi diminuir a qualidade JPEG durante o upload da imagem no meu servidor antes de criar a postagem do Facebook utilizando a classe WideImage para PHP com o seguinte código:

```
 //Classe para manipular a qualidade da imagem
    require('WideImage/WideImage.php');

    $imagem = WideImage::load($tmpFile);
    $imagem->saveToFile(PASTA_UPLOAD . '/' . $_GET['filename'], 85);
```

Aqui reduzi a qualidade para 85% e consegui diminuir e muito o tamanho e a taxa de compressão durante o upload do Facebook.